# Building Chrome Reference App

Tags: database, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, chromebook

I am new to chrome app development and had a question on databases.

I want to build a reference app for a tabletop rpg that I play. My goal is to create a flat database table that holds all of the information (Thousands of rows) that I can make queries to from the app. (An instant search bar that parses the database)

What is the best DB to use for something like this?

I keep seeing IndexedDB referenced, but that doesn't seem to apply to what I want to do.

Preferably, I would like this information to be available to the user offline.

Any tips??

Comment: It's not clear why IndexedDB is not what you want. Anyway, Chrome has WebSQL (despite being deprecated by W3C it has its advantages over IDB so it stays in Chrome).

Comment: @wOxxOm do you think i could use IndexedDB for this project?

Comment: Like I said, why not? :-) There are several wrapper libraries too.